# If an open set $U \subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is diffeomorphic to an open set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ then...

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds

Consider the problem asked in my smooth manifolds assignment:

> If an open set $U \subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is diffeomorphic to an open set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ then prove that n=m.

I think the question means that there exits a diffeomorphism f (say) from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Now, I thought of proving that such map f cannot be both one -one or onto.But I am unable to argue because f is not given.So, how should I try proving that if such map is both 1-1 and onto (assuming that it exists), m=n.

If there is some other way of proving that m=n, that is also welcome.

Comment: As a rule, linear spaces are simpler than curved spaces. Consider the derivative $df_{x} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. What is its rank?

Comment: You (or they) forgot to add the word "nonempty" in front of the word "set."

Comment: $f$ may not be given, but an important fact about $f$ *is* given, namely the hypothesis: $f$ is a diffeomorphism from (say) $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$. Now the question is: how do you apply that hypothesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F : U \rightarrow V$ be a diffeomorphism and let $p \in U$. Then the derivative
$DF_p : T_pU \rightarrow T_{F(p)}V$ is an **isomorphism of vector spaces**. Since $T_pU$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$T_{F(p)}V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, we must have that $n = m$.

Comment: Can you give a proof how $DF_p$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces? This result is not covered in my course.

Comment: Hi, the derivative is a linear transformation, you know that, right? But an isomorphism is exactly an invertible linear transformation, which is the case for a diffeomorphism.